# Extraction of coordinates of corners using Harris Corner detection ,and also retention of coordinates of points not lost during movement

Tags: python, opencv

Its a school project i am working on .I want to detect and extract coordinates of corners .As this is a screen capture ,things will move ,so i want to retain the points that are not lost during the movement ,and get the new coordinates .Please help me .

I am using python

Currently I am using this for corner detection,if someone has a faster method please let me know :

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time

last_time=time.time()
while(True):
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,640)))
    print ('Loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
    last_time=time.time()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(screen,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray=np.float32(gray)
    dst=cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
    dst=cv2.dilate(dst,None)
    screen[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]


    cv2.imshow('window',screen)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF== ord('q') :
         cv2.destroyAllWindows()
         break
```

Comment: Did you figure out the right answer to this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link which has answer to your problem.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/186538/to-find-the-coordinates-of-corners-detected-by-harris-corner-detection/

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = '1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#find Harris corners
gray = np.float32(gray)

dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)
ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst,0.01*dst.max(),255,0)
dst = np.uint8(dst)

#find centroids
ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)

#define the criteria to stop and refine the corners
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids),(5,5),(-1,-1),criteria)
#here u can get corners
print (corners)

#Now draw them
res = np.hstack((centroids,corners)) 
res = np.int0(res) 
img[res[:,1],res[:,0]]=[0,0,255] 
img[res[:,3],res[:,2]] = [0,255,0]
cv2.imwrite('1.png',img)
```

Comment: Links should be used as supplementary resources only. Links can go dead, or the content on the other side can be changed to no longer answer the question. Please edit your answer to include the information that your link points to.